# SQL Inject through form is not working in PHP 5.6

Tags: php, mysqli, mariadb, sql-injection

I was trying to do SQL Injection (SQLi).

My Form is:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="POST">
   <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Nama Properti</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="property_name">
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php if(isset($errors)) echo "<p class='errlog'>" . $errors . "</p>"; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>               
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="submit-form" value="Kirim" >
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And my action is:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit-form"])) {

        if (!empty($_POST["property_name"])) {

            $mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "belajar");
            if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
                exit();
            }
            $property_name = $_POST["property_name"];
            echo $property_name; // produce 'x'); DROP TABLE kelas_lain;--
            $sql = "INSERT INTO kelas_lain (property_name) VALUES (". $property_name .")";
            echo "<br>" . $sql; // produce INSERT INTO kelas_lain (property_name) VALUES ('x'); DROP TABLE kelas_lain;--)

            if ($sql_query = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
                echo "<p class='successlog'>Success !</p>";
                echo "Returned rows are: " . $sql_query->num_rows;  
                $sql_query->free_result();
            }else{
                echo "<p class='errlog'>There is an error with SQL !</p>";
            }

            $mysqli->close();


        }else{
            $errors = "Mohon Isi Form !";                   
        }

    }
?>
```

I passed this `'x'); DROP TABLE kelas_lain;--` through the input user form, but i get an error `echo "<p class='errlog'>There is an error with SQL !</p>";` instead of successfully did this command `INSERT INTO kelas_lain (property_name) VALUES ('x'); DROP TABLE kelas_lain;--)` which would drop kelas_lain table.

I did  `echo $sql;` it showed :

INSERT INTO kelas_lain (property_name) VALUES ('x'); DROP TABLE kelas_lain;--)

And i think all is correct.

**Additional**

While i have successfully done (SQLi) by passing the query through the url.

The passed query is :
index.php?**id=1 UNION SELECT password FROM siswalogin where id=1**
This is the code :

```
<?php 
   /*
    * Check if the 'id' GET variable is set
    */
    if (isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);

        /* Setup the connection to the database */
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'belajar');

        /* Check connection before executing the SQL query */
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
            exit();
        }

        /* SQL query vulnerable to SQL injection */
        $sql = "SELECT username
        FROM siswalogin
        WHERE id = $id";

        /* Select queries return a result */
        if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
            while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){
                print($obj->username);
            }
            echo "<br>" . $id; // = 1 UNION SELECT password FROM siswalogin where id=1
        }
        /* If the database returns an error, print it to screen */
        elseif($mysqli->error){
            print($mysqli->error);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: pass  'x') " ; DROP TABLE kelas_lain;-- I think you forgot pass " in input

Comment: or INSERT INTO kelas_lain (property_name) VALUES ('x'); DROP TABLE kelas_lain;-- ) pass a space after --

Comment: @bahram I have add more space at the end of my value, so :

` 'x'); DROP TABLE kelas_lain;-- `

It still not working.

Comment: `query` only processes one statement. For multiple statements, there's `multi_query`. That's probably what's preventing the injection here.

Comment: Is that caused by multiple statements query are rejected or something else ?

Comment: By the way why do i get down arrow here ?

Comment: `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements are more vulnerable because the injection can be at the expression level (in the `WHERE` clause), thereby leading to other rows being updated or deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons (especiallyy sql injection) the `mysqli_query()` function doesn't support execution of multiple sql statements.

Instead of you have to use `mysqli_multi_query()` function (which should never be used to process content of web forms).

By default MariaDB/MySQL server doesn't support execution of multiple SQL statements, unless the client flags `CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS` and `CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS` are set. However these options don't exist in PHP.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. i am new in programing language and want to start.
Your answer adding more knowledge on me.